# Trying to create a method that can write to Console or Form application

Tags: c#, client, client-server

I'm working on a general server and a client programs. The problem I'm facing is when I'm in the OnDataReceived in my client and server I don't know what to do with the data. Ideally it should output the received data into a window but I don't know if it will be a Form or Console application. So the question is how do I create a general method that can handle both or if that is not possible what should I do instead?

The code I'm working with:

```
            SocketPacket theSockId = (SocketPacket)asyn.AsyncState;

            int iRx = theSockId.m_currentSocket.EndReceive(asyn);
            char[] chars = new char[iRx + 1];
            Decoder decode = Encoding.Default.GetDecoder();
            int charLength = decode.GetChars(theSockId.dataBuffer, 0, iRx, chars, 0);
            String szData = new String(chars);

            //Handle Message here

            WaitForData();
```

And the socket packet class:

```
    class SocketPacket
    {
     public Socket m_currentSocket;
     public byte[] dataBuffer = new byte[1024];//Buffer to store the data by the client

     public SocketPacket(Socket socket)
     {
        m_currentSocket = socket;
     }
    }
```

PS.
I don't know if needs to be known but I'm doing asynchronous Client/Server.

Comment: Are you trying to create a program to perform a particular function, or a reusable library? Not sure what you mean by 'general server and client programs'.

Comment: You can take a look at the MVP pattern. The presenter will just use view's method for displaying data, and the view will take care of whether to display in a console or form or html label.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your communication classes shouldn't care what happens to the data they receive. Instead, they should either make the data available to a class that wants it. One way to do so would be to provide a getData() method, which received data and then returned it to the caller. Even better would be to provide a DataArrived event, which was fired whenever you received data. That way, any number of consumers could listen for data, but your communication code doesn`t have to know which classes are listening or what they plan to do with the data.

**EDIT**:

A simple example:

```
public class MyClassWithEvent
{
    public delegate void DataArrivedDelegate(string data);
    public event DataArrivedDelegate DataArrived;

    public void GetSomeData()
    {
        // Communication code goes here; stringData has the data

        DataArrivedDelegate handler = DataArrived;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            // If you want to raise the event on this thread, this is fine
            handler(stringData);
        }
    }
}
```

In your listener class:

```
public MyListener
{

    public MyListener(MyServer server)
    {
        // Sets MyListenerMethod to be called when DataArrived is raised
        server.DataArrived += MyListenerMethod;
    }

    public void MyListenerMethod(string data)
    {
        // Do something with the data
        Console.WriteLine(data);
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay, I'm not sure how I would create an event like that. Don't think I have used (custom) events, so any (mock)example would be great.

Comment: I'm not quite sure how this works, i.e. would this be part of my client and server class? And if so will GetSomeData be called by OnDataReceived? It could be that I'm misunderstanding this completely.

Comment: The class up there could be either (or both) of the client and server classes. You just go about your communications code as normal, and then when you receive data, you raise the event (as shown above) so that listeners can do something with your data. I`ll update the sample to show a listener.

Comment: Okay, so if I understand this correctly. I just use szData instead of stringData. Then MyListener is part of whatever program is using my server/client (be it Form or Console application) and will fire whenever new data is placed inside the delegate? Also is the void method MyListener supposed to be MyListenerMethod or?

Comment: Yes, it should MyListenerMethod. That`s the basic idea, yes: allow other classes to `listen` for data, and have the client/server tell them when its there.

Comment: Okay this seems to be what I want, so I will mark your answer as the answer. I might revisit and ask you some more questions, if anything unexpected happens.

Answer (score 2):

Fire an event with the string?  I would help if the data buffer string was a member of the socket object - then you could fire an event with just the socket object & your event-handler, whatever it turns out to be, would have everything it might need to decide what to do with the data.

Rgds,
Martin

Comment: Ok I should have included the SocketPacket class (which I now have) which indeed does have the DataBuffer. But could you give an example of how the event-handler would look like and also how I create an event. Have never used them (to my knowledge).

Answer (score 1):

I would create an interface where I can write the event information, something like IEventSink. So the OnDataReceived works with an instance of IEventSink and call a Write method on it.
Then I will have 2 implementation of the interface: one that write on the console and one that write on a form.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to implement strategy

```
interface IOutputStrategy
{
    void Output(string message);
}

class ConsoleOutput:IOutputStrategy
{
    public void Output(string message)
    {
        Console.Writeline(message);
    }
}

class FormOutput:IOutputStrategy
{
    public void Output(string message)
    {
        // output where you want
    }
}
```

and on Server / Client you will proeprty of type `IOutputStrategy`

```
//Server
IOutputStrategy instance = new ConsoleOutput();

//Client
IOutputStrategy instance = new FormOutput();
```

And then in OnDataReceived callback you can use current IOutputStrategy instance to output message

```
instance.Output(szData);
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

This is a good location for Dependency Injection.

1. Create an interface (we'll call it ISiemsen for now) that has a string property called "ShowTheResult"
2. Now, in whatever object you want to be able to show the result (form, console app, web form...) you implement the ISiemsen interface
3. Inside the property set for "ShowTheResult" you assign the value to whatever fills the need for that object. (If it is a console you execute a console.WriteLine(value), if it is a form, you assign the value to a textbox)
4. Change your worker process to accept reference to your worker function and let it send the response where ever it needs to go.

   ```
   protected void getResults(ISiemsen siemens ... ) 
    {
      SocketPacket theSockId = (SocketPacket)asyn.AsyncState;
      int iRx = theSockId.m_currentSocket.EndReceive(asyn);
      char[] chars = new char[iRx + 1];
      Decoder decode = Encoding.Default.GetDecoder();
      int charLength = decode.GetChars(theSockId.dataBuffer, 0, iRx, chars, 0);
      String szData = new String(chars);


      WaitForData();
   //Handle Message here
      siemsen.ShowTheResult(theResult);
    }
   ```

Using this technique the UI element doesn't know or care where the data comes from and worker process doesn't know or care where the going... it is 'loosely coupled'.